# Computation within log space

Tags: probability, bayes-factors, logarithm, underflow

What is the conversion of the following equation into log space?

$bf2 = 1 + (p * (bf1 - 1))$

Given log.bf1 (log Bayes factor), how do I get to log.bf2 without having to compute bf1, but instead using log.bf1?

Context: Numerical issues are arising because bf1 is often very large or very small. Hence, the computations are performed in log space to avoid numerical over/underflow.

Comment: Please explain what "numerical issues" are arising and (if possible) tell us why they happen.  For instance, would it be because $\text{bf}_1$ is very large, very close to $0,$ very close to $1,$ or something else?

Comment: Thanks. I have added a clarification to the question.

Comment: Have a look at how other people have defined functions such as log1p_exp, that should help.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently using numerical work arounds like that. The aim of my question was check if there really aren't any mathematical tricks I could use instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify the notation, write $x$ for $\text{bf}_1$ and $x^\prime$ for $\text{bf}_2.$  By subtracting $1$ from each side, write their relation as

$$y^\prime = x^\prime - 1 = p(x - 1) = py.$$

Let $s = \operatorname{signum}(y)$ be the sign of $y$ (equal to $1$ when $y\gt 0,$ $-1$ when $y \lt 0,$ and $0$ when $y=0$).  Multiplying by $s$ to make both sides nonnegative (assuming $p\ge 0$) allows us to take logarithms, giving

$$\log(s y^\prime) = \log(s y) + \log(p).$$

Thus,

> By representing the information in terms of $s = \operatorname{signum}(x-1)$ together with $\eta = \log|x - 1|,$ the update step merely adds $\log(p)$ to $\eta.$  After a sequence of updates you can recover the final value of $x$ from the final value of $\eta$ as $$x = s \exp(\eta) + 1.$$